# C# WPF MVVM: Multibinding to code-behind property not handling the correct updated value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, multibinding

I have an WPF button which "IsEnabled" property is bound to a property in code-behind "ReadOnly" and a property in view model "Enabled":

**View** (I only post the important part in which I want to focus, I do not post other components in view here):

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow1" 
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
        >
     <Window.Resources>
          <converters:BooleanAndConverter x:Key="BooleanAndConverter"/>
     </Window.Resources>

            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button1">
                <Button.IsEnabled>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanAndConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Enabled" />
                        <Binding ElementName="MainWindow1" Path="ReadOnly" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.IsEnabled>
            </Button>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind**:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new myViewModel();

            InitializeComponent();

            if (someCondition)
                 this.ReadOnly = true;
            else
                 this.ReadOnly = false; 
        }

        private bool readOnly = true;
        public bool ReadOnly
        {
            get
            {
                return this.readOnly;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.readOnly == value)
                    return;

                this.readOnly = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Converter**:

```
namespace WpfApplication1.Converters
{
    public class BooleanAndConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //foreach (object value in values)
            //{
            //    if ((value is bool) && (bool)value == false)
            //    {
            //        return false;
            //    }
            //}

            if (values != null)
            {
                if (values[0] is bool && values[1] is bool)
                {
                    bool vmState = (bool)values[0];
                    bool readOnly = (bool)values[1];  // <--- HERE readOnly always is true

                    return (vmState && !readOnly);
                }
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("BooleanAndConverter is a OneWay converter.");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that "readOnly" variable within "Convert" method in "BooleanAndConverter" class is always true. So when I set:

**this.ReadOnly = false;**

from constructor in code-behind, the attached "ReadOnly" property in button1 multibinding (in the view) it is always true and it is always being passed as true to the converter instead of false. Why? The another property "Enabled" that is used in multibinding and comes from view model is being updated correctly.

Should I implement INotifyPropertyChanged in code-behind and do a OnPropertyChanged("ReadOnly") within the set in "ReadOnly" property in code-behind? It seems that ReadOnly property in code-behind has always the same value (true) that was initialized for first time in the code-behind constructor.

Comment: Yes you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or make it a dependency property, unless the only place you set this property is constructor. In that case just move its initialization _before_ InitializeComponent()

Comment: you should also check out MVVM pattern and move the ReadOnly property to the ViewModel where the ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Evk Yes, this property is only updated on the code-behind for first time since I check user role. If user role is different from administrator, for example, viewer role, then I disable some components (button) in the view. Then is no longer updated from anywhere. So by moving "ReadOnly" property initialization before initializeComponent is working and ok for me. The only disadvantage is to remember to put this before initialization and don't forget and move it after initialization in future. So I will have a look to dependency properties as well.

Comment: @Evk Regarding INotifyPropertyChanged I don't like to implement it in the code-behind, better in view model.

Comment: @Steve Yes, another possibility would be to move this code-behind property to view model where INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented. Then from code-behind update it since my logic to decide whether this property is true or false is in code-behind

Comment: @Steve Also I think that moving this property to view model and update it from code-behind through some kind of call, and then from view model propagate the change through OnPropertyChanged to the view is an inecessary go and come back (loop) again to the view. Also I think this is a change on UI so corresponding to the view, not to the view model.